# Magento 2: How to add filter in custom graphql?

Tags: magento2, query, graphql

I have created a module with graphql schema where I will get the custom collection. Now I need to add a filter based on a few fields so I referred to this [blog](https://www.magentoassociation.org/commerce-co-op/full-article/how-to-create-your-first-custom-graphql-query-in-magento-2) but I need to use 2 fields in the filter logic. Need your guidance on this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!